# completeness of propositional logic from $(a \to b) \to ((\lnot a \to b) \to b)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, fake-proofs, proof-theory

At [Wikipedia/Propositional_Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Another_outline_for_a_completeness_proof) I found the following proof sketch of the completeness of propositional logic systems which (among other things, I assume) admit the proof-by-case-analysis formula $(p \to s) \to ((\lnot p \to s) \to s)$:

> If a formula is a tautology, then there is a truth table for it which
>   shows that each valuation yields the value true for the formula.
>   Consider such a valuation. By mathematical induction on the length of
>   the subformulas, show that the truth or falsity of the subformula
>   follows from the truth or falsity (as appropriate for the valuation)
>   of each propositional variable in the subformula. Then combine the
>   lines of the truth table together two at a time by using "(P is true
>   implies S) implies ((P is false implies S) implies S)". Keep repeating
>   this until all dependencies on propositional variables have been
>   eliminated. The result is that we have proved the given tautology.
>   Since every tautology is provable, the logic is complete.

I don't quite follow this. Let me try an example: we wish to apply this method to prove the hypothesis introduction formula $a \to (b \to a)$ [which will likely lead to circular reasoning if it's an axiom in our system, but let's ignore that].

First we split it up into subformulae $a$ and $b \to a$ and prove their truth valuations from the truth assignments of their variables; so $a \to a$ and $\lnot a \to \lnot a$ (this assumes that we can prove reflexivity of implication, $p \to p$). We also recur on $b \to a$ and show $b \to b$ and $\lnot b \to \lnot b$, and repeat the proof for a.

Then, having conditionally proven the leaf formulae, we construct a proof that $(b \to a)$ has the truth value it has when its subformulae (variables) have the values they have, e.g. we prove the four following statements:

1. $\lnot a \to \lnot b \to (b \to a)$
2. $\lnot a \to b \to \lnot (b \to a)$
3. $a \to \lnot b \to (b \to a)$
4. $a \to b \to (b \to a)$

**Questions**: Is it really these four? How do we prove them?

Having proven them, I see how the case analysis theorem lets us combine statements 1 and 3 into $(\lnot b \to (b \to a))$, but it doesn't apply to 2 and 4 because they have opposite conclusions.

**Question**: What's the induction step being hinted at in the quote? Does it work at all?

It seems to me like this is a clumsy restatement of the completeness proof by Kalmar from 1935. Am I off base?

Comment: The extract from the Wikipedia article is extremely badly written and unclear. The idea is that for any given assignment of truth values to the propositional variables of a formula (say $a$ is true and $b$ is false in your example of the formula $a \to (b \to a)$), you can find a proof that that assignment results in the same truth value for the formula as is given by the truth table (i.e., a proof that $a \to \lnot b \to (a \to (b \to a)$ in this case in your example). Now repeated use of proof by case analysis shows that a formula that is validated by the method of truth tables is provable.

Comment: The complete proof is in Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA34), CRC Press (6th ed 2015), page 34-35.

Comment: And you are right: it is Kalmar's 1935 proof.

Answer (score 0):

Having read (most of) Kalmar's proof, I know what's missing from the quoted fragment.

There's a sketch of half of the real proof at https://people.ucalgary.ca/~rzach/blog/2014/11/kalmars-compleness-proof.html.

Part one: if $a, \ldots, z \vdash \varphi$ and $a, \ldots, \lnot z \vdash \varphi$ then $a, \ldots, y \vdash \varphi$ (where $a, \ldots, y$ can be negated or not). This is shown using the deduction theorem to conclude $a, \ldots, y \vdash z \to \varphi$ and $a, \ldots, y \vdash (\lnot z) \to \varphi$. Using the case analysis formula, one concludes $z$. By induction one eliminates all assumptions.

This assumes we can construct a proof of $z \to \varphi$ and $(\lnot z) \to \varphi$ under assumptions $a, \ldots, y$ where this implication holds. In Kalmar's proof, he uses various axioms to construct such proofs, working inductively in the height of $\varphi$.

- Kalmar uses $\alpha \to \lnot \lnot \alpha$ when $\varphi$ is a negation
- Kalmar uses $(\lnot \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ and $\alpha \to \beta \to \alpha$ and $\alpha \to (\lnot \beta) \to \lnot (\alpha \to \beta)$ when $\varphi$ is an implication.
- Kalmar uses $(\alpha \to (\beta \to \gamma)) \to (\alpha \to \beta) \to (\alpha \to \gamma)$ to show $\alpha \to \alpha$, which is used in one of the cases.

Thus, it does not immediately follow that case analysis plus deduction theorem (e.g. via S and K combinator axioms) is a complete system.

Kalmar's article is available at http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/projectdirs/kalmar/pdf/35_act_sci_math.pdf